# Apache proxypass redirect to multiple unix sockets

Tags: server, apache2, reverse-proxy, gunicorn

I have a server that runs multiple flask instances using gunicorn.socket, and an apache2 server is configured to proxy the request:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ProxyPass / unix:///run/gunicorn_site0.sock|http://127.0.1.1/
        ProxyPassReverse / unix:///run/gunicorn_site0.sock|http://127.0.1.1/

        # RewriteEngine On
        # RewriteRule      ^/0/(.*)$ unix:///run/gunicorn_site0.sock|http://127.0.1.1/$1  [P,L]

        # ProxyPass /1 unix:///run/gunicorn_site1.sock|http://127.0.1.1/
        # ProxyPassReverse /1 unix:///run/gunicorn_site1.sock|http://127.0.1.1/

        # ProxyPass /2 unix:///run/gunicorn_site2.sock|http://127.0.1.1/
        # ProxyPassReverse /2 unix:///run/gunicorn_site2.sock|http://127.0.1.1/

</VirtualHost>
```

As shown above, if I only enable `site0`, everything works fine, i.e., when I type 127.0.1.1/ in the browser, it proxies to `gunicorn_site0.sock` with url 127.0.1.1/

However, what I really want to do is to allow the follows:

```
# Typed in address bar                         Actual request
http://127.0.1.1/0/some/path        ->         gunicorn_site0.sock 127.0.1.1/some/path
http://127.0.1.1/1/some/path        ->         gunicorn_site1.sock 127.0.1.1/some/path
http://127.0.1.1/2/some/path        ->         gunicorn_site2.sock 127.0.1.1/some/path
```

I tried multiple ways with RewriteRule but with no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with a "first site" in /0 instead of / ? there is no reason it fail, but i think you first proxypass "eat" all sub urls:

```
ProxyPass /0 unix:///run/gunicorn_site0.sock|http://127.0.1.1/0
ProxyPass /1 unix:///run/gunicorn_site1.sock|http://127.0.1.1/1
ProxyPass /2 unix:///run/gunicorn_site2.sock|http://127.0.1.1/2
```

However you will probably need to make sure all python app are ok running in a "sub-directory". (eg by setting SCRIPT_NAME in gunicorn env)